# Linux command to retrieve a byte range from a file

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I know that `head` and `tail` can take `-c` option to specify a byte offset. I'm looking for a way to efficiently extract a byte range from a large log file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The DareDevil of the Unix commands, `dd` to the rescue!

```
dd if=yourfile ibs=1 skip=200 count=100
```

That would start from byte 200 and show 100 next bytes, or in other words, bytes 200-300. `ibs` means dd only reads one byte at a time instead of the default 512 bytes, but still writes out in default 512 byte chunks. Go and see if `ibs` harms the performance, I hope not.

Comment: For a file of 782090815 bytes, I got these times:

`time dd if=file.txt | wc -l` = 00:00:03s. `time dd if=file.txt ibs=1 count=782090815 | wc -l` = 9:05:19

Answer (score 16):

If your interest is in the bytes, would `od` be of more interest.

```
-j, --skip-bytes=bytes
-N, --read-bytes=bytes
```

So to read the 16 bytes starting at byte 1024, and output in ascii

```
od -j 1024 -N 16 -a /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dd if=logfile of=pieceoflogfile skip=startingblock count=#ofblocks` (possibly with `bs=1` to get one-byte blocks, otherwise it uses 512 byte blocks).  Not sure how efficient it is to tell it to write one byte at a time, though.

Comment: Well, if concerned regarding efficiency — 2 `dd`'s can be pipe-chained together (the 1st might cut fat piece and the 2nd would do fine job over the pipe, not disk), but `dd` has not only `bs` but separate `ibs` and `obs` as well, so at least it could output with bigger blocks than reading.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file isn't excessively large (e.g. several GB or so), piping from one to the next is as efficient as you'll get, short of writing your own program to do so.

```
head ... file | tail ...
```

(Or the other way around. Whichever.)

Comment: tail should go first for large offsets, otherwise the beginning of the head output is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, and asked for a "linux" command in the title, but python is perfect for this and comes with most linux distributions.  It's as easy as this:

`python -c 'f=open("myfile.txt","rb");f.seek(100);print(f.read(100));f.close()' | SomeOtherProgram`

`f.seek(n,0)` goes n bytes from the start of the program, and `f.read(n)` reads the number of bytes you want.

I've not found any other options that make it that easy.

Answer (score 0):

u can use splice in linux, this example in c program, and then name it fastcat.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define __IO_BUFSIZE (8192)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
loff_t in_off = 0;
loff_t out_off = 0;
off_t lenData;
int StartReadDataAt=-1;
int AmountOfData=-1;
char location[100];
int err = -1;
static int buf_size = __IO_BUFSIZE;
struct stat stbuf;

for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
{
    if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'f') //argument for StartReadDataAt
    {
    int totalIndeks =strlen(argv[i])-3;
    char data[totalIndeks];

    strncpy(data, argv[i] + 3,totalIndeks);
    data[totalIndeks]='\0';
    StartReadDataAt=atoi(data);

    StartReadDataAt=StartReadDataAt-1;
    if(StartReadDataAt == -1){
        StartReadDataAt=0;
        }
    }
    else if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'c') //argument for AmountOfData
    {
    int totalIndeks =strlen(argv[i])-3;
        char data[totalIndeks];

        strncpy(data, argv[i] + 3, totalIndeks );
    data[totalIndeks]='\0';
        AmountOfData=atoi(data);
    }
    else                        //argument for Location
    {
        strncpy(location, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
    location[strlen(argv[i])]='\0';
    }
}


    FILE* f = fopen(location, "r");         //open
    if(!f) {
        printf("file %s not found:",location);
        exit;
    }


    int IN = fileno(f);


    int p[2]; 
    if(pipe(p) < 0)
    {
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    close(IN);
    //perror("pipe:");
        exit;
    }
    
    if(fstat(IN, &stbuf) < 0)
    {
       // perror("fstat:");
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        close(IN);
    exit;
    }
    lenData = stbuf.st_size;
    if ( AmountOfData != -1 && StartReadDataAt != -1 ){
                in_off=StartReadDataAt;
        if((StartReadDataAt+AmountOfData) > lenData){
            lenData= lenData-StartReadDataAt;
        }else{
                    lenData= AmountOfData;
        }
    }
    else if ( AmountOfData != -1 ){
        lenData= AmountOfData;
    }else if(StartReadDataAt != -1){
        in_off=StartReadDataAt;
        lenData=lenData-StartReadDataAt;
    }

       // fprintf( stderr, "lendData : %i\n", lenData);

    while(lenData>0)
    {

    if(buf_size > lenData){
        buf_size = lenData;
    }

    loff_t len = splice(IN, &in_off, p[1], NULL, buf_size, SPLICE_F_MOVE);  //input to p[1]
        if(len < 0)
        {
        close(p[0]);
            close(p[1]);
            close(IN);
            exit;
    }

        lenData=lenData-len;
    //fprintf( stderr, "lendData : %i\n", lenData);

        
        err = splice(p[0], NULL,STDOUT_FILENO, NULL, len, SPLICE_F_MOVE); //p[0] to STDOUT_FILENO

    }
    
    err = 0;

}
```

compile

```
gcc ./fastcat.c -o ./fastcat
```

example

```
./fastcat -f=100 -c=10000 /root/document
```